# Android turning off flash on second launch of activity

Tags: java, android, flashlight

Im trying to make a very basic flashlight app. When the user opens the app no layout will be inflated, the flashlight will just turn on. Once the user opens the for the second time the flashlight will turn off. It seems as if turning on the flashlight is no hassle but when it comes to turning it off when the app launches for the second time,thats where im a little unsure. Im not too sure how to tackle this problem, any help would be appreciated!

Heres what i have so far:

```
package com.example.rifatrashid.lighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private boolean haslight;
private Integer val = 0;
private Camera camera;
private Camera.Parameters parameters;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    haslight = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature((PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH));
    if(!haslight) {

    }
    camera = Camera.open();
    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    val++;
    if(val>1)
        val=0;
    switch (val){
        case 1:
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            break;
        case 0:
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should *ALWAYS* have a UI for any app - your design is flawed.

Comment: why dont you use shared preference to store and check value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you already use a class variable to toggle the light, so it looks like all you have to do is move the whole thing from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`. However, the whole thing may not behave correctly since you don't have a UI. Try it, however. You should probably implement a transparent content view to say the least.

**Edit:** to implement a unnoticable UI window, just have a blank activity, and use the `finish()` keyword in the `onResume()` method and `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` to not show a screen flash.

Hope this helps,